# time_t rounded to minutes

Tags: c++, mfc

i am using an API which deals with time_t. Now i have a result also from API which retrieves data in time_t also but the problem is the first one only needs the date, hour and minute but the data i retrieve includes seconds, how can i remove the seconds from the data>

```
     m_chart.period =   PERIOD_M1;
     m_chart.start  =   m_trades[x].open_time;
     m_chart.end    =   m_trades[x].close_time;
     m_chart.mode   =   CHART_RANGE_IN;
     candles        =   m_manager->ChartRequest(&m_chart, &stamp, &chart_total);
```

where m_trades[x].open_time is the data that i retrieve with seconds on it and the m_chart.start is the filter data that only needs date, hour and minutes.

I hope you can help me with this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't need seconds, just ignore seconds.

Comment: @IInspectable how? since the m_trades[x].open_time includes also seconds.

Comment: Divide by 60....

Comment: time_t is in seconds so you need to subtract the remainder seconds like: `t -= (t % 60)` // minutes_only = total_seconds - seconds_part

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what you're asking. The unit of `time_t` is one second. More precisely it denotes the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00, Jan 1, 1970 UTC. You probably need the functions described [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`time_t` is in seconds so if you want it to contain only round minutes you have to to subtract the remainder seconds like:

```
t -= (t % 60) // minutes_only_sec = total_seconds - seconds_reminder_seconds
```

e.g

```
time_t secs = 2 * 60 + 14;           // 2:14

time_t min_only = (secs - secs % 60);

std::cout << "seconds:" << secs << " / " << min_only << std::endl;
std::cout << "minutes: " << secs / 60 << ":" << (secs % 60)
              << " / " << min_only / 60 << ":" << (min_only % 60) << std::endl;
```

has the following output:

> seconds: 134 / 120
>
> minutes 2:14 / 2:0

And if you want to round it up you can test:

```
if (secs % 60)
{
    min_only += 60;
}
```

I would recommend use [`std::chrono::duration`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration). It's a bit longer:

```
    time_t min_only = std::chrono::seconds(
          std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(std::chrono::seconds(secs))
                                           ).count();
```